# How to type Vue3 plugin function for Typescript - error is of type 'unknown'

Tags: typescript, plugins, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a plugin with some functions inside.

```
export default {
    install: (app:any) => {

        app.provide('translate', (translations:Array<Object>, key:string) => {

            let translation = translations.find((item:any) => {
                return item[key] && item.locale === lang
            });
            .......

            return translation

        })
```

Then when I want to use it in component via inject()

```
const translate = inject('translate')
```

I am getting an **error TS18046: 'translate' is of type 'unknown'.**

I dont understand what should I set up for this case.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the solution is to write

```
const translate = inject<Function>('translate')
```

but this solution lead to another error which says **Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' as a function** [Solution is to use composables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77322577/cannot-invoke-an-object-which-is-possibly-undefined-as-a-function-from-vue3-pl) instead of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-provide-inject) when using `inject` with typescript, the default type will be "unknown".

You can pass another generic type and it should fix your problem.

```js
const translate = inject<YourInjectType>('translate')
```

In this case, the `inject` function might also return `undefined`, so you can pass another argument as the default value

```js
const translate = inject<YourInjectType>('translate', 'defaultValue')
```

Comment: I dont understand. <YourInjectType> is return value of the function or what? I try to use <string> but I am getting two new errors:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures. 254             'title': translate(item.translations, 'company_category'),
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
error TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

254             'title': translate(item.translations, 'company_category'),

Comment: The `YourInjectType` is the type of the value returned by the `inject` function.  Since you are providing a function, my guess is your type needs to be the function type. Something like `(translations:Array<Object>, key:string) => string`.

Comment: I dont understand. This is what I should write as type?
`(translations:Array<Object>, key:string) => string`
I tried to use :function but this type does not exist.

Comment: It's the type of what you are expecting the `inject` function to return. I'm not sure how you are using the `provide` function, but it should be what you are expecting the `inject` function to return. If it still doesn't work, maybe you have an issue in your `provide` function.

Comment: Its simple example from documentation provide->inject. I am using it according documentation. Is there any type like function? This is why I am asking a question. Documentation does not say anything about it.

Comment: It doesn't, you're right. I've only used `inject`/`provide` with primitive or object, I'm unsure about function. Technically, there's no reason it shouldn't work. But I can't help you more than that. You're gonna have to figure out yourself. Sorry.

Comment: This seems to work `const translate = inject<Function>('translate')`