# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' as a function from Vue3 plugin

Tags: typescript, plugins, vuejs3, undefined

I have a Vue3 plugin with some global functions which really exists and work fine. I am using inject command to use it in components.

```
const translate = inject<Function>('translate')
```

Now I should be able to use it like simple call of a function.

```
const parsedCategories = computed(() => {
    const categories = settingsApi.value?.companyCategories ? settingsApi.value.companyCategories : [];

    if( !categories.length ) return []

    let result = [];

    categories.forEach((item: any) => {
        result.push({
            'title': translate(item.translations, 'company_category'),
            'value': item.id
        })
    })

    return result
})
```

This line

```
'title': translate(item.translations, 'company_category'),
```

Have a problem while build **Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'**
Solution for this should looks like

```
'title': translate ? translate(item.translations, 'company_category') : '',
```

This is bad idea. I dont want to write this conditions to use plugin functions.
Can somebody tell me please what am I doing wrong? Plugin is implemented according documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am still wonder how to solve this problem cause this make Vue3 plugins completely useless with Typescript. But I found a solution. I rewrote all the functions in plugin as [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#mouse-tracker-example) and now it does not throw an error with undefined type.